# What is the “down” service at port 2022?

Tags: port, services, nmap

According to NMAP and IANA port 2022 TCP belongs to the service down:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2022/tcp open  down
```

But what is down? I cannot find anything about it. Is there any document explaining this odd thing?

Edit: Just to clarify, I do not want to know that down is a service, that is obvious. I want to know more about it. What was it used for, is there any specification or documentation available? Also, why is it so unknown?

Comment: Specifically, `down` is the IANA-registered Well Known Service on TCP port 2022: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=36

Comment: No this does not suffice as an answer. I opened this question, as this earlier question does not go into detail on what down actually is. My question is, what is down? I already wrote that nmap and iana says it is the service "down" and the output of nmap clearly indicates that down is the service and not the state.  So what is down? Is there any documentation or was someone just drunk like 30 years ago when they wrote the list and this thing does not actually exist at all?

Comment: The `down` service perhaps dates from a long time ago. The company that reserved port 2022 might no longer exist.